# What are the various files at cdimage.ubuntu.com daily builds?

Tags: release-management

On http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ there are various files. they can be categorized by two ways.

1. Architecture

   - i386
   - amd64
   - amd64+mac
2. Extension of file

   - .OVERSIZED
   - .manifest
   - .metalink
   - .list
   - .iso
   - .iso.zsync

I'm sure about the arch, but what do the various extensions mean? How are they meant to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- .OVERSIZED is just a placeholder to say that the ISO won't fit on a standard CD
- .manifest is the full list of debian packages that this ISO will provide (contents of live filesystem)
- .metalink is meant to be used by the Wubi installer
- .list is just the file listing
- .iso is the image you'll need to download to burn a CD or to give to startup disk creator.
- .iso.zsync is a zsync metafile meant to be used by the `zsync` tool (Partial/differential file download client over HTTP), visit http://zsync.moria.org.uk/ for further details.